# How to set conditions when JSON parser can't find a JSON object

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, adt

In this for loop, my code looks for "name", "count", and "id", but sometimes the "count" object is not available in the JSON response. How can I set conditions when the "count" object is not present?

```
for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject albumData = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Global.albumArray.add(albumData.getString("name"));
        if (albumData.getString("count")==null){
            Global.countArray.add("?");
        }
        else{
            Global.countArray.add(albumData.getString("count"));
        }
    Global.linkArray.add(albumData.getString("id"));
}
```

The "if" statement doesn't work, obviously, but it is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can use the JSONException throwed by getString [look here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String))

Comment: So I guess the most conventional way would be to throw a try and catch around the getString("count")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method called optString which means optional String - `optString(String name, String fallback)`

name = your key

fallback == default value if your key is null

So now you won't have to put any if else condition

Comment: Even better. This is probably a better approach. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String s;
try {
    s = albumData.getString("count");
} catch(JSONException ex) {
    // something to do if there isn't "count" item
} finally {
    // something to do if there is "count"
}
```